# Fuji AEL button not working

Tags: camera-settings, fujifilm

For some reason the AEL button on the rear of my X-T4 is doing nothing; i.e. I press it and I don't see the AE lock symbol to the right of the metering icon - either temporarily (when the button is held down) or permanently (when the AF/AE buttons are set to work as an on/off switch rather than push to hold).

This is with an Fujinon XF lens. I've tested it in both manual and auto bracketed ISO, and in all focusing modes, and all metering modes.

I've also checked the button is assigned correctly (to AE-lock only) and verified it is physically working by assigning it to something else.

Additionally, setting AF/AE lock mode to "switch" (Button/Dial setting menu) doesn't seem to have any effect on the 'AF ON' button behaviour - i.e. AFL is still only shown on screen when the button is depressed, not toggled.

**Update:** A fix for *that* problem is to change the button assignment for AF-ON from AF-ON to AF LOCK ONLY, then pressing it toggles the blue AFL indicator while back-button focusing still works in manual mode.

Face-detection is OFF (apparently this stops various other things from working).

I've done a *Set Up Reset* too.

Firmware: body <strike>v1.24</strike> v1.30 (lens v1.05) - both latest versions

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the latest version of the camera's firmware?

Comment: Did you reset the camera to factory settings?

Comment: @hpchavez Just did that (a Set Up Reset, which apparently does everything except some date/time and connection stuff). No difference to either problem.

Comment: @MichaelC body 1.24, lens (XF 16-80) 1.05. (Unfortunately my memory card is stuck in the slot at the moment and the 'thin piece of cardboard' trick doesn't seem to be working…)

Comment: @MichaelC actually, (with care), I've subsequently been able to get the card out and update the firmware to 1.30 and test again, though there was nothing obvious in the release notes

Comment: Asking the obvious: You do have the AF mode set to AF-S? And not AF-C?

Comment: @MichaelC it wasn't that, but I have fundamentally misunderstood how AEL works, as I didn't have shutter speed on auto :(  90% of the time when I've been shooting, I dial a specific shutter speed in first according on the subject. Apologies for not realising (it's obvious in hindsight though not many of the articles about AEL spell it out…)

Comment: @WilliamTurrell Oh! I misread your original question to be about AF instead of AE, but the concept holds. If you want the camera to continue to update a parameter continuously until the instant you push the shutter button fully, it won't lock that parameter at any time prior to the shutter button being pressed fully.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have shutter-speed set to AUTO for AEL to work.

Without the camera being on auto, it can't set the shutter speed, which is obvious, unfortunately it had been so long since I'd used auto-exposure I'd forgotten that's all it actually does.

Realised after comparing the behaviour of my Fuji X70, which likewise displays the shutter speed as soon as you press or toggle your AE button.